# Verizon app on UK Pixel

Tags: bloatware, google-pixel

I have an original Pixel, running Android 8.1.0(OPP5.170921.005), but the update seems to have added the Verizon app. (I'm in/from the UK and use EE.)

I have 2 questions:

- Is this expected behaviour?
- Can I remove it without rooting my device?

Screenshot of added app:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems like it is no possible to uninstall this app, you can only disable it as it is a system app and you need root access to uninstall system apps.

Comment: Is it meant to be in the image I got from android beta, and is there a setting to get a clean image instead?

Comment: All factory images can be downloaded from here: https://developers.google.com/android/images